# New unknown users appearing on ubuntu, virus?

Tags: 20.04, 19.10, users, malware

there are these two users periodically appearing in my ubuntu system ('jicofo','jvb') I have deleted them twice (in 19.10) but they reappeared again, so I thought I'd look into it and turns out they own a good amount of files, I am yet to check if there are any particularly interesting ones, in the meanwhile is that possible I got a malware somewhere in ubuntu 19.10? If so, would my upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 do something or nah?
What should my next course of action be? Backup and reinstall? If those users own those files, even if I delete all the ones they own I think I would backup them too wouldn't I?
Thank you for taking the time to read this, hope someone can help me :)

Comment: I guess this is somehow related to video conferencing app. JITSI. if you installed it, just uninstall and use the web version.

Answer (score 2):

There is a video conferencing app called **Jitsi Meet**. This app creates both users. If you have it installed, that would explain why they keep coming back.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was related to Jitsi, do you know if this app is malicious? I'll uninstall it right away, thank you